# mysqli NUM_COLUMNS for profile completion progress bar

Tags: mysql

I am working on a profile completion progress bar, i have multiple tables which contain profile data. just like num_rows is it possible to get num_columns to see how many columns in each table contain data for that perticular user ??

Whats the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

No there's no num_columns alike function, you have to query the technical tables of the information schema.

To get all the columns of a table :

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
```

To count all the columns of a table

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
```